# Proper use of const for defining functions

Tags: javascript, function, constants, ecmascript-6

Are there any limits to what types of values can be set using `const` in JavaScript, and in particular, functions? Is this valid? Granted it does work, but is it considered bad practice for any reason?

```
const doSomething = () => {
   ...
}
```

Should all functions be defined this way in ES6? It does not seem like this has caught on, if so.

Comment: You seem to ask multiple questions: 1) *"I am interested if there are any limits to what types of values can be set using const in JavaScript"* No. 2) *"Is this valid?"* Yes.  3) *"is it considered bad practice for any reason"* I guess it hasn't been around for long enough to say anything about that but I don't see why this should be pad practice. It's not much different from `var doSomething = <function def>;`. 4) *"Should all functions be defined this way in ES6?"* Seems to cumbersome to me. I like function declarations. Everyone their own.

Comment: The way I see it (opinion, not a fact), it makes sense if you want to disallow redefining functions. Whether it's sane, or whether it has some functional use - that's debatable. If you think it fits your use scenario, I don't *think* someone can argue your decision and deem it bad practice.

Comment: I guess the question is what you want to achieve with `const`. Do you want to prevent yourself from overriding the function? I'd assume you know your code to not do this anyway. Do you want to express the intent of `doSomething`, i.e. that it holds a function and does not change its value? I think function declarations communicate this intent clearly as well. So, if you need "runtime protection" from overriding, go for it. Otherwise I don't see much benefit. Of course if you primarily used to use `var foo = function() {};`, I would use `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: @FelixKling, "I'd assume you know your code to not do this anyway." - this is pretty bad argument. Otherwise, there's no sense in `const` at all.

Comment: I'd like to add that using `const` instead of `function` to define a "function" is a regression in readability. I just started JS again after a 4-5 year hiatus and came across a bunch of `const` to declare `function` code and it is wrecking my brain.

Answer (score 465, accepted):

There's no problem with what you've done, but you must remember the difference between function declarations and function expressions.

A function declaration, that is:

```
function doSomething () {}
```

Is hoisted entirely to the top of the scope (and like `let` and `const` they are block scoped as well).

This means that the following will work:

```
doSomething() // works!
function doSomething() {}
```

A function expression, that is:

```
[const | let | var] = function () {} (or () =>
```

Is the creation of an anonymous function (`function () {}`) and the creation of a variable, and then the assignment of that anonymous function to that variable.

So the usual rules around variable hoisting within a scope -- block-scoped variables (`let` and `const`) do not hoist as `undefined` to the top of their block scope.

This means:

```
if (true) {
    doSomething() // will fail
    const doSomething = function () {}
}
```

Will fail since `doSomething` is not defined. (It will throw a  `ReferenceError`)

If you switch to using `var` you get your hoisting of the variable, but it will be initialized to `undefined` so that block of code above will still not work.  (This will throw a `TypeError` since `doSomething` is not a function at the time you call it)

As far as standard practices go, you should always use the proper tool for the job.

Axel Rauschmayer has a great post on scope and hoisting including es6 semantics: [Variables and Scoping in ES6](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html)

Comment: Would just like to add that es6 classes uses const internally to protect the class name from being reassigned within the class.

Comment: One subtle difference between ***a*** `function a(){console.log(this);}` and ***b***  `const a=_=>{console.log(this);}` is if you call it like `a.call(someVar);`, in ***a***, it will print `someVar`, in ***b***, it will print `window`.

Answer (score 207):

Although using `const` to define functions seems like a hack, it comes with some great advantages that make it superior (in my opinion)

1. It makes the function immutable, so you don't have to worry about that function being changed by some other piece of code.
2. You can use fat arrow syntax, which is shorter & cleaner.
3. Using arrow functions takes care of `this` binding for you.

example with `function`

```js
// define a function
function add(x, y) { return x + y; }

// use it
console.log(add(1, 2)); // 3

// oops, someone mutated your function
add = function (x, y) { return x - y; };

// now this is not what you expected
console.log(add(1, 2)); // -1
```

same example with `const`

```js
// define a function (wow! that is 8 chars shorter)
const add = (x, y) => x + y;

// use it
console.log(add(1, 2)); // 3

// someone tries to mutate the function
add = (x, y) => x - y; // Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
// the intruder fails and your function remains unchanged
```

Comment: 1. Immutability is a real benefit, but it is very rare for someone to actually overwrite a function. 2. Fat arrow syntax is not shorter unless your function can be an expression. `function f(x, y) {` is 18 characters, `const f = (x, y) => {` is 21 characters, so 3 character longer. 3. Keeping this binding only matters if the functions are defined inside a method (or other function which has meaningful this). At the top level script it is pointless.

I'm not saying you are wrong, just that the reasons you mention are not terribly relevant.

Comment: One advantage of the old fashioned function syntax is during debugging it has a name.

Comment: I would use linters to prevent re-binding the function declaration.

Comment: @Nakedible - I also prefer using `function` but in your comparison you're forgetting the `function` needs `return` while the other method doesn't. (Unless I'm unaware of a shortcut?)

Comment: "You can use fat arrow syntax, which is shorter & cleaner." - Sometimes shorter and cleaner isn't better if it makes the code harder to follow for other developers. Good programming isn't just writing short code that works, it's also writing maintainable code among other things.

Comment: Using the `function`  keyword also makes the outline in VSCode more descriptive, because it represents `const f = function() {}` as a variable and `function f() {}` as a function

Comment: 'Cleaner' is a relative concept. I would accept it for one or two liners functions, but if you have some more operations to perform inside the function or you have to just return a complex object I'm not so sure

Comment: Also, it doesn't "take care of the `this` binding for you" it just doesn't bind it. This is a common misconception.  When you access `this` from an arrow function you are getting it from the closure. Most of the times it's what you want, but not always

Comment: "fat arrow syntax, which is shorter & cleaner" it is the other way around. it is longer. And cleaner is subjective. I would say it is messy and harder to read. And i like arrow functions, but not when i create a regular function in module scope.
And noone is going to mutate a function.

Answer (score 89):

It has been three years since this question was asked, but I am just now coming across it.  Since this answer is so far down the stack, please allow me to repeat it:

> **Q:** I am interested if there are any limits to what types of values can be
>   set using const in JavaScript—in particular functions. Is this valid?
>   Granted it does work, but **is it considered bad practice for any
>   reason?**

I was motivated to do some research after observing one prolific JavaScript coder who *always* uses `const` statement for `functions`, even when there is no apparent reason/benefit.

In answer to "*is it considered bad practice for any reason?*" let me say, IMO, yes it is, or at least, there are *advantages* to using `function` statement.

It seems to me that this is largely a matter of preference and style.  There are some good arguments presented above, but none so clear as is done in this article:
[**Constant confusion: why I still use JavaScript function statements**](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/constant-confusion-why-i-still-use-javascript-function-statements-984ece0b72fd) by  medium.freecodecamp.org/Bill Sourour, JavaScript guru, consultant, and teacher.

**I urge everyone to read that article, even if you have already made a decision.**

**Here's are the main points:**

> ### Function statements have two clear advantages over [const] function
>   expressions:
>
> #### Advantage #1: Clarity of intent
>
> When scanning through
>   thousands of lines of code a day, it’s useful to be able to figure out
>   the programmer’s intent as quickly and easily as possible.
>
> #### Advantage #2: Order of declaration == order of execution
>
> Ideally, I want to declare my code more or less in the order that I
>   expect it will get executed.
>
> This is the showstopper for me: any value declared using the const
>   keyword is inaccessible until execution reaches it.
>
> What I’ve just described above forces us to write code that looks
>   upside down. We have to start with the lowest level function and work
>   our way up.
>
> My brain doesn’t work that way. I want the context before the details.
>
> Most code is written by humans. So it makes sense that most people’s
>   order of understanding roughly follows most code’s order of execution.

Comment: Can you comment slightly more on the clarity of intent? I get #2, but as far as I can tell #1 is just a (pre?) reiteration of #2. I can think of a case, i.e. functions having their own `defaultErrorHandler` const assigned as an anonymous function that I can then call from promise handlers. This would enable me to optionally 'override' this default error handler within functions as I needed to. Some just need to return an error object and others need to return an http response, varying levels of verbosity. Yet the code structure can be a familiar pattern regardless.

Comment: Maybe my idea is too convoluted though! Just wrapping my head around some new practices, haven't spent a ton of time implementing them yet. Just finding I really like `.then( res.success, res.error )` a lot more than the anonymous functions I was declaring to just call `res.success(value);`. Having a `.then( ..., defaultErrorHandler)` common pattern could be nice, with a top level defined defaultErrorHandler function, and optionally have a `const defaultErrorHandler = error => { ... }` declared within a function scope as desired.

Comment: @JakeT. RE "Can you comment slightly more on the clarity of intent? ".  Well, first of all, that statement was not made my me, but by freecodecamp.org/Bill Sourour, the author of that article.  But it makes real common sense to me.  If I read "function tomorrow()" then I immediately know it IS a function.  But if I read "const tomorrow = () =>", I have stop for a moment and parse the syntax in my head to finally determine, OK, yeah, it's a function.

Comment: Another thing, if I have a long script written by someone else, and I want to see all of the functions, I can do a quick search on "function" to find them.  Or even better, I can write a quick JS RegEx to extract all of the functions.  IMO, the "const" statement is just for data (not functions) that will NOT change.

Comment: @JMichaelTX - I get what you're saying about reading `function tomorrow() { }` versus `const tomorrow = () => { }`, but surely that's just a case of being more used to seeing one as opposed to the other? After a day or two, you should adjust to being just as capable of spotting the new pattern... Also, if you're after the functions during a search or regex, replacing `function ` with `) => {` is just as good, if not better, as you avoid any comments that happen to have the word function in it.

Answer (score 16):

There are some very important benefits to the use of `const` and some would say it should be used wherever possible because of how deliberate and indicative it is.

It is, as far as I can tell, the most indicative and predictable declaration of variables in JavaScript, and one of the most useful, BECAUSE of how constrained it is. Why? Because it eliminates some possibilities available to `var` and `let` declarations.

What can you infer when you read a `const`? You know all of the following just by reading the `const` declaration statement, AND without scanning for other references to that variable:

- the value is bound to that variable (although its underlying object is not deeply immutable)
- it can’t be accessed outside of its immediately containing block
- the binding is never accessed before declaration, because of Temporal Dead Zone (TDZ) rules.

The following quote is from [an article](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/var-let-const) arguing the benefits of `let` and `const`. It also more directly answers your question about the keyword's constraints/limits:

> Constraints such as those offered by `let` and `const` are a powerful way of making code easier to understand. Try to accrue as many of these constraints as possible in the code you write. The more declarative constraints that limit what a piece of code could mean, the easier and faster it is for humans to read, parse, and understand a piece of code in the future.
>
> Granted, there’s more rules to a `const` declaration than to a `var` declaration: block-scoped, TDZ, assign at declaration, no reassignment. Whereas `var` statements only signal function scoping. Rule-counting, however, doesn’t offer a lot of insight. It is better to weigh these rules in terms of complexity: does the rule add or subtract complexity? In the case of `const`, block scoping means a narrower scope than function scoping, TDZ means that we don’t need to scan the scope backwards from the declaration in order to spot usage before declaration, and assignment rules mean that the binding will always preserve the same reference.
>
> The more constrained statements are, the simpler a piece of code becomes. As we add constraints to what a statement might mean, code becomes less unpredictable. This is one of the biggest reasons why statically typed programs are generally easier to read than dynamically typed ones. Static typing places a big constraint on the program writer, but it also places a big constraint on how the program can be interpreted, making its code easier to understand.
>
> With these arguments in mind, it is recommended that you use `const` where possible, as it’s the statement that gives us the least possibilities to think about.

Source: https://ponyfoo.com/articles/var-let-const

Comment: This question is about `function` vs `const` not `var` vs `const`. And this answer itself is an indication that the use of `const` to define a `function` is not a readability enhancement and in fact a readability regression in modern JS. Because this answer already confused it for variables, not functions.

Comment: noone nowadays uses "var" anyway. Those who do are usually beginner or have been sleeping for 20 years.

Answer (score 10):

There are special cases where **`arrow functions` just won't do the trick:**

1. If we're changing a method of an external API, and need the object's reference.
2. If we need to use special keywords that are exclusive to the `function` expression: `arguments`, `yield`, `bind` etc.
   For more information:
   [Arrow function expression limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

**Example:**

I assigned this function as an event handler in the `Highcharts` API.
It's fired by the library, so the `this` keyword should match a specific object.

```
export const handleCrosshairHover = function (proceed, e) {
  const axis = this; // axis object
  proceed.apply(axis, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); // method arguments
};
```

With an arrow function, `this` would match the declaration scope, and we won't have access to the API obj:

```
export const handleCrosshairHover = (proceed, e) => {
  const axis = this; // this = undefined
  proceed.apply(axis, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); // compilation error
};
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Existing Answers Summary

1. **Function Declarations vs. Expressions**: Emphasizing the differences in hoisting and scope.
2. **Immutability and Arrow Functions**: Discussing the benefits of using `const` for immutability and arrow function syntax.
3. **Readability and Execution Order**: Arguing for traditional function declarations due to clarity and natural flow.
4. **Practical Limitations of Arrow Functions**: Highlighting situations where traditional functions are necessary, like needing `this` context or special keywords.
5. **Benefits of `const`**: Focused on predictability and restrictions that improve code understanding.

#### Gap Identified

None of the answers deeply explore the implications of using `const` with async functions, particularly in modern JavaScript development where asynchronous operations are common. They also don't address the modular and scalable design patterns that `const` functions can encourage, especially in large-scale applications.

#### MyAnswer

##### Use Case: Async Functions and Modular Design

In modern JavaScript, especially with the prevalence of asynchronous operations (like API calls), defining functions as constants can be particularly advantageous when combined with async/await syntax. This approach not only ensures immutability but also encourages a modular design pattern.

Using `const` for async functions promotes a clear and concise structure, especially when these functions are exported from a module. It helps in maintaining a consistent coding style across a codebase, particularly in large-scale applications where readability and maintainability are crucial.

##### Example

```js
// Defining an async function using const
const fetchData = async (url) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
};

// Usage in an async context
const processData = async () => {
    const data = await fetchData('https://api.example.com/data');
    console.log('Received Data:', data);
};

processData();
```

In this example, `fetchData` is an asynchronous function defined with `const`. This ensures that `fetchData` won’t be accidentally reassigned elsewhere in the code, maintaining the integrity of the function. Additionally, this style aligns well with the modern async/await syntax, providing a clear, promise-based structure for handling asynchronous operations.

##### Conclusion

While the traditional function declaration has its merits, especially in terms of readability and hoisting behavior, the use of `const` for defining functions, particularly async functions, offers significant benefits in terms of code stability, modular design, and adherence to modern JavaScript patterns. This approach is highly recommended in scenarios involving asynchronous operations and when working on large-scale applications that require a consistent and maintainable codebase.