# How can I combine two functions that fire on the same class name?

Tags: jquery, function, datatables, click

I have a `function` that fires when I click on item inside my jquery datatable item.

```
$('.table tbody').on( 'click', '.item', function (e) {
   alert("clicked");
});
```

I have an item with the same class outside the datatable, that works with this `function`:

```
  $('.item').on( 'click', function (e) {
     alert("clicked");
  });
```

What is inside the `function` is for both the same. Is there a way to combine these two functions into one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function first

```
const func = () => {
   alert("clicked")
};
```

and execute this inside both the event listeners

```
$('.table tbody').on( 'click', '.item', func);
$('.item').on( 'click', func);
```

**Update:**

And if you want the event inside the function then you can use arrow functions too.

```
const func = (e, el) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   alert($(el).attr("data-id"));
};

$('.table tbody').on( 'click', '.item', function(e){
     func(e, this);
});
$('.item').on( 'click',function(e){
     func(e, this);
});
```

Comment: why do I have to use `const func`? Why cannot I use `function clicked() {
     alert("clicked");
}`

Comment: `const func` is a function expression in ES2015 JavaScript. You can write `function clicked() { alert("clicked"); }` this too and it will work just fine.

Comment: I need `function (e)` because I later have to use `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @Jarla you can do that too. See the updated answer :) It is a choice you need to make based on the syntactic you are following in your project.

Comment: Thank you, just wanted to learn, what does it mean to do it that way

Comment: @Jarla glad to help. Read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040703/proper-use-of-const-for-defining-functions-in-javascript. Do mark it correct if it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, I have to wait to more minutes until they let me mark it

Comment: I tested it. I am using for example this variable in my function `var id = $(this).attr("data-id");` and now with your function if `alert(id)` the output is `undefined`

Comment: You need to pass this as an argument and in the function fetch the data attribute using this passed param.

Comment: like this `const func = (e, id) => {`and `$('.edit-item').on( 'click', func(id));`?

Comment: yes, ok, just never worked with thi const func. So I was confused. Thank you for help!