# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am doing my where clause outside the findAll() method to allow the user to send filter's or not in the request body. One of the values on my request body is categoryId that can be sent or not.

This is my code :

```
     const where = {}
        if (categoryId) {
            where = { '$subcategories.category_id$': categoryId
         }
        } 

    try {
            const establishments = await establishment.findAll({
                attributes: [
                    "id",
                    "description",
                    "latitude",
                    "longitude",
                    [sequelize.literal(' (6371 * acos ( '
                        + 'cos( radians(' + latitude + ') ) '
                        + '* cos( radians( latitude ) ) '
                        + '* cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' + longitude + ') )'
                        + '+ sin( radians(' + latitude + ') )'
                        + '* sin( radians( latitude ))))'), 'distance']
                ],
                include: [{
                    attributes: [],
                    model: subcategory, as: 'subcategories',
                    required: false,
                },
                {
                    attributes: ["id", "name"],
                    model: certificate, as: 'certificates',
                    required: false,
                },
                ],

                where: {
                    where
                },

                establishments: ['id'],
            });
 } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(400).json({ Error: "Error while fetching the establishment" });
    }
```

Error given :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()
```

Comment: The error is actually pretty clear. You declare `where` as a constant and then try to assign it a value.

Comment: Yes your right.

Comment: Also I seem to have an invalid value on  the $subcategories.category_id$, am I doing something wrong? @Aioros

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper use of const for defining functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040703/proper-use-of-const-for-defining-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: I am having this error on $subcategories.category_id$ saying invalid value, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign values to `const` variables once it is declared.

either use `let`

`let where = {}`

or

```
const where = {}
if (categoryId) {
  where['subcategories.category_id'] = categoryId
}
```

change `where: { where }` to `where: where`

Comment: it's also giving me an invalid value in $subcategories.category_id$, am I doing this wrong?

Comment: try removing the $ signs

Comment: try `where : { ...where }`

Comment: sorry did not understood, can you repeat? :)

Comment: or you can just do `where: where`

Comment: also, how can I put several wheres there?

Comment: what do you mean by several where ?

Comment: like if I wanted to search also by categoryName (also with null check)

Comment: ohh, just keep adding to the where object to the top. just use `where['key'] = value` instead of reassigning the whole thing.

Comment: can you show a quick example on the code you've writen?

Comment: same as the `const` example I have written, check for your condition in the `if` and keep adding to the where object.

Comment: @ AkashDathan can you give me a help in this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61282783/how-to-pass-object-as-a-data-type-to-a-data-model-in-sequilize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212032/discussion-between-jose-nobre-and-akash-dathan).

Answer (score 1):

```
const where = {}
```

If you create a variable with **const**, then you can't redeclare it again. You should use **let** instead.

```
let where = {}
```