# How to prompt user to try to input again

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here is my code. I am wondering if there is a way to prompt the user to try to input a title again if they fail to meet the requirement of being less than 200 characters long. Thanks for any help!

```js
message.author.send(
 'Lets get to work!\nPlease enter the title of your event. (Must be shorter than 200 characters)'
);
message.channel
 .awaitMessages(
  (response) =>
   response.author.id === message.author.id && response.content.length < 200,
  {
   max: 1,
   time: 10000,
   errors: ['time'],
  }
 )
 .then((collected) => {
  message.author.send(`I collected the message : ${collected.first().content}`);
  let title = collected.first().content;
 })
 .catch(() => {
  message.author.send('No message collected after 10 seconds.');
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it in a function, then just repeat the function over and over again.

```js
message.author.send(
 'Lets get to work!\nPlease enter the title of your event. (Must be shorter than 200 characters)'
);
const collecter = () => {
 message.channel
  .awaitMessages(
   (response) => response.author.id === message.author.id, // remove requirement from function
   {
    max: 1,
    time: 10000,
    errors: ['time'],
   }
  )
  .then((collected) => {
   if (collected.first().content.length < 200) {
    // add it in the callback
    message.channel.send('bla bla bla went wrong! Please try again');
    collector(); // repeat the function
   }
   message.author.send(
    `I collected the message : ${collected.first().content}`
   );
   let title = collected.first().content;
  })
  .catch(() => {
   message.author.send('No message collected after 10 seconds.');
  });
};

collector();
```

Comment: Hiya. This is a neat solution I wish I thought of. Although it makes me feel a bit uncomfy being recursively called, I think itll be alright since I dont imagine the user messing up the input a bunch of times. Thanks! I will give it a go :) .

Comment: I'd recommend reading the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040703/proper-use-of-const-for-defining-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies it well. Appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)