# Using const instead of let for javascript function expressions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In a lot of javascript code **let** is used to create a function expression. It seems to make more sense to use **const** since almost always the variable holding the function almost never changes.

Are there any drawbacks for using **const** instead of **let** ?

(ps. I have to teach javascript, and I like to use "best practices" when explaining concepts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper use of const for defining functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040703/proper-use-of-const-for-defining-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: "*In a lot of javascript code `let` is used to create a function expression*" - citation needed.

Comment: Are you talking about arrow function expressions or actual `function`s? For the latter, function declarations are still best practice.