# How to convert options api to composition api in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm using Vue.js version 3. Here is my full code with dummy data and options API with filters and sorting,
and everyting works very well

```
<template>
  <h5>List of Products</h5>

        <h3>Filter</h3> 
        <button v-on:click="resetOptions">Reset</button>
        <button v-on:click="sorting">Sorting</button>
        <button v-on:click="sorting2">Sorting2</button>
        <select v-model="category">
            <option value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
            <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
            <option value="Stationary">Stationary</option>
        </select> 
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" v-model="city"  value='Roma' /> 
        <label for="test"> Roma</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test2" id="test2" v-model.trim="city" value='Barselona'  />
        <label for="test2"> Barselona</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test3" id="test3" v-model.trim="city" value='Milano'  />
        <label for="test3"> Milano</label>
        </div>
         <!-- <select v-model="city">
            <option value="Barselona">Barselona</option>
            <option value="Roma"> Roma </option>
            <option value="Milano">Milano</option>
        </select>  -->

        <input type="text" v-model="name" placeholder="Filter By Name"/>

        <label for="vol">Price (between 0 and 1000):</label>
    
        <input type="range" v-model.trim="range" min="0" max="1000" step="10"/>  
        <ul>
            <li v-for="product in filterProducts" :key="product.name"> Product Name : {{product.name}} - Price : {{product.price}} ({{product.category}}) 
                {{product.city}}
            </li>
        </ul>
</template>

<script>
import getPosts from '../composables/getPosts'
export default {
 data: ()=> ( {

            city:['Roma', 'Barselona', 'Milano'],
            category: '',
            name: '',
            range: '10000',
            products: [
                { name: "Keyboard", price: 44, category: 'Accessories', city:'Roma'},
                { name: "Mouse", price: 20, category: 'Accessories', city:'Barselona'},
                { name: "Monitor", price: 399, category: 'Accessories', city:'Roma'},
                { name: "Dell XPS", price: 599, category: 'Laptop', city:'Roma'},
                { name: "MacBook Pro", price: 899, category: 'Laptop', city:'Roma'},
                { name: "Pencil Box", price: 6, category: 'Stationary', city:'Barselona'},
                { name: "Pen", price: 2, category: 'Stationary', city:'Milano'},
                { name: "USB Cable", price: 7, category: 'Accessories', city:'Milano'},
                { name: "Eraser", price: 2, category: 'Stationary', city:'Roma'},
                { name: "Highlighter", price: 5, category: 'Stationary', city:'Roma'}
            ]

        }),

              computed: {
            filterProducts: function(){
                return 
 this.filterProductsByName(this.filterProductsByRange(this.filterProductsByCity(this.filterProductsByCateg 
 ory(this.products))))
            },

        },
        
        methods: {

            filterProductsByCategory: function(products){
                return products.filter(product => !product.category.indexOf(this.category))
            },

            filterProductsByName: function(products) {
                return products.filter(product => 
  !product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.name.toLowerCase()))
            },

            filterProductsByCity: function(products) {
                     return products.filter(product => this.city.indexOf(product.city) !== -1)
            },

             filterProductsByCity2: function(products) {
                 return products.filter(product => !product.city.indexOf(this.city))
             },

            filterProductsByRange: function(products){
                return products.filter(product => (product.price >= 0 && product.price <= this.range) ? product : '')
            },

            sorting:function(){
                this.products.sort((a,b)=>(a.price > b.price) ? 1 : -1)
            },
             sorting2:function(){
                this.products.sort((a,b)=>(a.price < b.price) ? 1 : -1)
            },

            uniqueCheck(e){
            this.city = [];
            if (e.target.checked) {
                 this.city.push(e.target.value);
               }
         },

            resetOptions:function(){
                this.category='',
                this.city='',
                this.name='',
                this.range='1000'
            },
        },

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

But I want to convert this to Composition API and I put dummy data in fake API. I made that API call and put it in the getProducts.js file. That file I imported on this page where I want to show that data. And that works fine. But I have a problem with converting functions from Options API to Composition API
Here is my code

```
<template>
  <div class='home'>
      <h1>Third</h1>
        <select v-model="category">
            <option value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
            <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
            <option value="Stationary">Stationary</option>
        </select> 
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" v-model="city"  value='Roma' /> 
        <label for="test"> Roma</label>
      </div>
      <div v-if="error"> {{error}} </div>
      <div v-if="products.length">
          <div v-for="product in filterProducts" :key='product.price'>
            <h3>{{product.name }}</h3>
            <h4>{{product.category}}</h4>
          </div>
      </div>
    <div v-else> Loading...</div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import { computed, ref} from 'vue'
import getProducts from '../composables/getProducts'

export default {
    components: {} ,
    setup(){ 

      const category = ref('')
      const city = ref('')
      const{products,error,load} = getProducts()

      load()

        function filterProductsByCategory (products){
              return products.filter(product => !product.category.indexOf(category.value))
          }
         function filterProductsByCity (products) {
               return products.filter(product => city.value.indexOf(product.city) !== -1)
            }

       const filterProducts = computed (()=> {  
        return filterProductsByCity.value(filterProductsByCategory.value(products.value))**
    }) 


      return {products, error, category, city, filterProducts, filterProductsByCity, filterProductsByCategory}
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

This is a part of my filter functions, It's problem in functions I think. I changed everything that I needed to convert Options API to Composition API

So here is just a part of filter logic but if someone helps me with this I will convert all code easily

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### `data`

1. Replace each data property with a [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref). We'll update their references within `setup()` when converting `methods` later.
2. Use [`onMounted`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#lifecycle-hooks) to call `load()` upon mounting the component.

```js
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import getProducts from '@/composables/getProducts'

export default {
  setup() {
    const { products, load } = getProducts()
    const category = ref('')
    const city = ref([])
    const name = ref('')
    const range = ref('10000')

    onMounted(() => load()) // load products

    return {
      // properties that the template needs should be returned here
      products,
      category,
      city,
      name,
      range,
    }
  }
}
```

#### `methods`

1. Declare the methods as function instances within `setup()`.
2. For all data properties that are now `ref`s, update their code references to unwrap the `ref` (i.e., `this.name` should be `name.value`, etc.).

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    //...
    const filterProductsByCategory = (products) => {
      return category.value
        ? products.filter((product) => !product.category.indexOf(category.value))
        : products
    }

    const filterProductsByName = (products) => {
      return name.value
        ? products.filter((product) => !product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.value.toLowerCase()))
        : products
    }

    const filterProductsByCity = (products) => {
      return city.value && city.value.length
        ? products.filter((product) => city.value.indexOf(product.city) !== -1)
        : products
    }

    const filterProductsByRange = (products) => {
      return range.value
        ? products.filter((product) => product.price >= 0 && product.price <= range.value)
        : products
    }

    const sorting = () => products.value.sort((a, b) => (a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1))
    const sorting2 = () => products.value.sort((a, b) => (a.price < b.price ? 1 : -1))

    const uniqueCheck = (e) => {
      city.value = []
      if (e.target.checked) {
        city.value.push(e.target.value)
      }
    }

    const resetOptions = () => {
      category.value = ''
      city.value = ''
      name.value = ''
      range.value = '1000'
    }

    return {
      //...

      // methods that the template needs should be returned here
      sorting,
      sorting2,
      uniqueCheck,
      resetOptions,
    }
  }
}
```

#### `computed`

1. Use [`computed`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#computed-values) to create a computed property, referencing the function instances and `ref`s created above in `setup()`.

```js
import { computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    //...
    const filterProducts = computed(() => {
      return filterProductsByName(
        filterProductsByRange(
          filterProductsByCity(filterProductsByCategory(products.value))
        )
      )
    })

    return {
      //...
      filterProducts,
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/converting-options-api-to-composition-api-forked-q5ows?file=/src/components/MyForm.vue)

Comment: Minor comment - using <script setup> instead of setup() makes for slightly more readable code as well. Main difference being that once can forgo returning the variables (filterProducts,  products, category, etc.), and that we can remove the export default {setup(){...}} wrapper. More readable, and I am not aware of any downsides.

Answer (score 2):

`<script setup>` **version** for composition api code can be done as follows.

```html
<script setup>
     import DemoComponent from "./Demo.vue"
     import { onMounted, ref, computed } from "vue";

     const demoVar = ref(""); //data property of options api
     const demoComputed = computed(()=>{
         return {};
     });  // computed property 

     //Methods can be declared in 2 ways
     //1st
     function demo(){
        //logic
     }

     //2nd
     const demoTwo = function(){};

     //lifecycle hook
     onMounted(() => {})
</script>
```

For more info on declaring methods and its uses please check [Proper use of const for defining functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040703/proper-use-of-const-for-defining-functions)

We don't need to return `const` and `function` at end of the script, with script setup everything is directly accessible to the template even `components`.

`<script setup>` provides more readability and avoids unnecessary errors due to missed out declarations in `return`. For more details [script setup](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html)