# Sending mail through JavaScript clicking html submit button

Tags: javascript, html, email

I am trying to send mail using JavaScript when submit button is clicked on the html webpage. Here is my HTML code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        .heading{
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
<body>

   <h2 class="heading">Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>
   <textarea name="myText" id="myText">this is a mail</textarea>
   <button onclick="sendMail(); return false">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `sendMail` function in JavaScript to process the email

```
 function myFunction(){
  var link="mailto:amarhutiappa@gmail.com"
  + "?cc=mrinal.annand@gmail.com"
  + "&subject=" + encodeURIComponent("This is my subject")
  + "&body="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsById('myText')).value
;

window.location.href = link;
}
```

I can not understand where I am doing wrong! Someone please suggest the right way

Comment: What this will do, essentially, is try to load a local email program to process the mailto link. That will likely work if the user has Outlook/Thunderbird/etc. configured properly, might work if they have something set up to route mailto links to the Gmail (or other web based email) web page or may not work at all. It is **not** actually using the *browser* to send email - just "set up" a message in an email application, *if configured to to do so*.

Comment: please ignore my bad english

Comment: ok , i have a doubt, can u pls tell me what this line means in javascript "?cc=mrinal.annand@gmail.com"

Comment: basically what cc means here?

Comment: cc = "Carbon Copy" which means that the email address should be included as another recipient.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit - Send an email directly via JavaScript

If you are looking to send an email without using html `mailto:` there is a library called [smtpJS](https://smtpjs.com/). View a simplified tutorial [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript/).

**BUT I WOULD NOT SUGGEST TO USE YOUR PERSONAL EMAIL HERE**

In your case you can use it like below

```js
const sendMail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const message = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('message').value)
    Email.send({
        Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
        Username : "username",
        Password : "password",
        To : 'them@website.com',
        From : "you@isp.com",
        Subject : encodeURIComponent("This is my subject"),
        Body : message
    }).then(
      message => alert(message)
    ).catch( err => {
        alert(err)
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <form method="post" onsubmit="sendMail(event)">
        <textarea name="message" id="message">Sample Text</textarea>
        <button type="submit">Send Email</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can setup your configuration as per your credentials. If you are using Gmail you can use the credentials mentioned in this [article](https://kinsta.com/blog/gmail-smtp-server/)

**Disclaimer**

I did not test it out completely since I was reluctant to use my personal mail address and I do not have a mail address for production. Please do further research and edit this answer post if necessary

### Old Answer

There were some errors in your code and here is the fixed code...

```js
const sendMail = () => {
  const mailAdress = "someone@example.com"
  const ccRecipients =  "mrinal.annand@gmail.com"
  const subject = encodeURIComponent("This is my subject")
  const body = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('myText').value)
  const  link= `mailto:${mailAdress}?cc=${ccRecipients}&subject=${subject}&body=${body}`
  window.location.href = link;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        .heading{
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
<body>

   <h2 class="heading">Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>
   <textarea name="myText" id="myText">this is a mail</textarea>
   <button onclick="sendMail()">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

First of all you haven't defined the function `sendMail()` in your JavaScript code and instead defined `myFunction()`.

Second it's better to assign the mail address, cc recipients, subject and body as variables since they can be made dynamic or to easily change the hardcoded values. Next you can concatenate the variables using [ES6 Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to have in ease in reading and writing the code.

Thirdly, the below code is incorrect.

```
 encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsById('myText')).value
```

You should pass the value of text area to the `encodeURIComponent()` function. For that first you must get the value in text area by `document.getElementsById('myText').value` and pass that value into `encodeURIComponent()`. The corrected code will look like this

```
encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('myText').value)
```

Also if you want to understand the use of HTML `mailto`, [refer this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/)

Comment: @Mrinal Anand Using `const` is a better approach to define the functions and the variables in JavaScript ES6. Specially here I used it to make the function immutable. So you don't have to worry about function being changed by other parts of code. Refer more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42803030/13833218)

Comment: yeah, that was a mistake,  i mean that myFucntion() call , what i was trying to do is to send a mail from mrinal.annand@gmail.com to amarhutiappa@gmail.com when submit button is clicked....what else is needed

Comment: I'll add some further explanation to the answer. I have corrected the errors in your code and given the corrected snippet. Does it work?

Comment: i changed ccRecipient to amarhutiappa@gmail.com  and  mailAdress to mrinal.annand@gmail.com, but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you explain on how it does not work? Do you mean that email is not being sent?

Comment: yes, the email is not being sent, i included the js file in the html file using script tag

Comment: To be clear, after including the above corrected snippet your default email application opens up with the correct data right?

Comment: @MrinalAnand Remember that `mailAdress` means the mail address to which the message is sent to. If the email address you are using in your default email application is same as the address to which the mail is sent, it won't work. In your case. In your case if your email is _mrinal.annand@gmail.com_ and you are trying to send an email to the same address it won't work

Comment: @MrinalAnand  assuming that you are using gmail here is an example. Suppose you have logged on to your account using  _sender@gmail.com_ Then you can send an email to _reciever@gmail.com_ and add a Cc recipient to _anotherreceiver@gmail.com_. But you can not send an email to _sender@gmail.com_. Did you understand?

Comment: here i am logged in to mrinal.annand@gmail.com and sending to ama...@gmail.com. and i have removed that Ccrecipient, now it should work,right?

Comment: yes. If it's not working, do you get any error messages? If so what are they?

Comment: OK. Does the code opens up the default email service with the added details?

Comment: i am using Gmail as the email service, if you mean that on clicking submit button whether Gmail is opening or not , then answer is no

Comment: i hope i got your point "with added details". if not, let me know what you mean by that

Comment: mm ok. Can you just elaborate what happens when you click the send button?

Comment: i read somewhere that it is not possible to send mail using pure javascript only, am i doing right? although answering your qstn -->nothing happens clicking on send button, even the console is empty before and after clicking

Comment: You can not mail a person via vanilla JavaScript but what you are trying above is to send an email by opening the default email application of the user. And I have provided a working solution for that above. I am not quite sure why nothing happens when you click the send button. Did you actually copy the code I have added in my answer? Did you try running the snippet actually? It works fine here...

Comment: yes, first i did copy paste the code given by you, updated the email addresses ( i mean someone@example.com   to   amar....@gmail.com ) and tried ...it didn't work,... included the javascript file in html file,...didn't work,....excluded Ccrecipient address,...didn't work....moved to sending mail using nodejs

Comment: are you able to send mails through this code only, on your computer?

Comment: my issue hasn't been solved yet!!! how can i upvote?

Comment: I am asking you to upvote if my answer gives a solution only!! And remember my original answer has already answered what you have asked!

Comment: i did upvote as you have put in a lot of time and energy for my issue and i am very thankful for all those..

Comment: @MrinalAnand It seems like I did not receive upvote yet. This answer gives the solution to your question and has corrected the error in your code that you have submitted. Please upvote the answer and accept it if it solves your problem