# How how to add line numbers next to highlihte.js code area?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, syntax-highlighting

I would like to align the rows of text with the numbers in the yellow vertical bar (without breaking the mouse pointer on the rows, because changing margin or padding also moves the pointer).

**PROBLEM:** As you can see from the image, the problem is that the first and second rows are not well aligned with the numbers in the yellow column. The rows in the black panel are created in the yellow empty spaces between the numbers

​
[image]

**HIGHLIGHT.JS:** I would have liked not to use the [Highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) library (to select the text color) in the question code, but i noticed that using Highlightjs adds css that creates additional empty space at the top-beginning of the black panel. WITHOUT [Highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) i have the **same problem**, but with Highlightjs the empty space is greater.

Even if you have never used [Highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/), it's not difficult and it's not a problem, below you will find the working snippet where everything is included. So to find the solution you have to use Highlightjs which already i inserted in html as tag and [CDN](https://highlightjs.org/#usage):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/vs2015.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

**DETAILS:** In `.numbers` css, i managed the vertical space between the numbers with the `line-height: 1.3` and also their size with `font-size: 16px`, so i would like the space and size to remain the same. I tried changing some `paddings` or `margins`, but doing so breaks the mouse pointer after the last letter of a word or breaks in other ways. I would like to get this or something very similar:

[image]

How can i align the rows to the numbers correctly?

**IMPORTANT: Attention to the broken mouse pointer on the rows, because the rows alignment problem seems solved, but the mouse pointer breaks and does not flash correctly on the rows, therefore it may be set in a wrong position between two rows.**

In case of help, please please use my code for the solution and not another example code, because as you can see my code is a bit peculiar. Thanks in advance to everyone

​

```js
/// JS CODE ROWS ///
const textarea = document.querySelector(".hilite-editor");
const numbers = document.querySelector(".numbers");

function updateLineNumbers() {
  const num = textarea.innerHTML.split("\n").length;
  numbers.innerHTML = Array(num).fill("<span></span>").join("");
}

// Update line numbers when the page loads
updateLineNumbers();

// Update line numbers when the textarea content changes
textarea.addEventListener("input", updateLineNumbers);

// WHEN I PRESS KEY
textarea.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (event.key === "Tab") {
    const start = textarea.selectionStart;
    const end = textarea.selectionEnd;

    textarea.innerHTML =
      textarea.innerHTML.substring(0, start) +
      "\t" +
      textarea.innerHTML.substring(end);

    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

/// JS CODE EDITOR ///

const elHTML = document.querySelector(`[data-lang="html"]`);
const elCSS = document.querySelector(`[data-lang="css"]`);
const elJS = document.querySelector(`[data-lang="js"]`);
const elPreview = document.querySelector("#preview");

const hilite = (el) => {
  const elCode = el.previousElementSibling.querySelector("code");
  elCode.textContent = el.textContent;
  delete elCode.dataset.highlighted;
  hljs.highlightElement(elCode);
};

const preview = () => {  
  const encodedCSS = encodeURIComponent(`<style>${elCSS.textContent}</style>`);
  const encodedHTML = encodeURIComponent(elHTML.textContent);
  const encodedJS = encodeURIComponent(`<scr` + `ipt>${elJS.textContent}</scr` + `ipt>`); 
  const dataURL = `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,${encodedCSS + encodedHTML + encodedJS}`;
  elPreview.src = dataURL;
};

// Initialize!

[elHTML, elCSS, elJS].forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("input", () => {
    hilite(el);
    preview();
  });
  hilite(el);
});

preview();
```

```css
/******** CODE EDITOR HIGHTLIGHTS.JS **********/  
/* Scrollbars */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}


.hilite {
position: relative;
background: #1e1e1e;
height: 120px;
overflow: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.hilite-colors code,
.hilite-editor {
padding: 1rem !important;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
white-space: pre-wrap;
font: 13px/1.4 monospace;
width: 100%;
background: transparent;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
}

/* THE OVERLAYING CONTENTEDITABLE WITH TRANSPARENT TEXT */
.hilite-editor {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
color: transparent; /* Make text invisible */
caret-color: hsl( 50, 75%, 70%); /* But keep caret visible */
width: 100%;
}
.hilite-editor:focus {
outline: transparent;
}
.hilite-editor::selection {
background: hsla(0, 100%, 75%, 0.2);
}

/* THE UNDERLAYING DIV WITH HIGHLIGHT COLORS */
.hilite-colors {
position: absolute;
user-select: none;
width: 100%;
}

#preview {
display: block;
background: #fff;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 0;
}

/* highlight.js customizations: */
.hljs {
background: none;
}


#preview.resizing {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/******** COUNT ROWS **********/  
.numbers {
 text-align: right;
 background: yellow;
 /* padding-right: 20px; */
 width: 35px;
 height: 200px;
 /* margin-right: 71px; */
 line-height: 1.3;
 font-size: 15px;
}

.numbers span {
 counter-increment: linenumber;
}

.numbers span::before {
 content: counter(linenumber);
 display: block;
 color: black;
}

/******** CONTAINERS **********/  
.container {
 /*max-width: 700px; */
 min-height: 16em;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
}

.container--tabs {
 list-style: none;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: stretch;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 background-color: #282828;

 .tab {
   min-height: 2em;
   padding: 7px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 127px;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #363636;
   color: white;
   transition: background-color 0.25s;
   border-right: 1px solid #5a5a5a;

   &:hover {
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
     transition: background-color 0.25s;
     color: white;
   }
 }

 .tabs--active {
   background-color: #1e1e1e;
   color: white;
   pointer-events: none;
 }
}

.content {
 display: none;
 padding: 0;

}

.content--active {
 display: flex;
 height: 800px;
}

h1 {
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
 font-weight: 700;
}

p {
 font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!-- Highlight js -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/vs2015.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container--content">
  <div class="content content--active">

    <div class="numbers">
      <span></span>
    </div>  

    <div class="hilite">

      <pre class="hilite-colors"><code class="language-html"></code></pre>
      <div
           data-lang="html"
           class="hilite-editor"
           contenteditable="true"
           spellcheck="false"
           autocorrect="off"
           autocapitalize="off"
           >&lt;h1 class="heading" title="test this" data-some='foo bar'>This is a Heading&lt;/h1>   
        &lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p></div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  
  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's so many things in your approach I corrected, I can just hope to mention some of them (at least the most relevant ones):

- **Edit:** Since contenteditable have many gotchas regarding inserting custom user-markup on keyboard combos (CTRL+B for bold etc...) or by copy/pasted content (like i.e: from VSCode) with preserved stylings (at least it seems in Firefox, since they don't accept the "plaintext-only" contenteditable attribute value) - here's a variant that uses `<textarea>`.
  The only hack here is that textareas have by default a scrollbar we need to get rid of by auto-updating the textarea height dynamically:
- set the scrollbars to the elements that now wraps numbers and hilite
- set the appropriate `height: max-content` to the numbers wrapper and to the hilite wrapper
- don't just split by `\n` newline. Resizing the browser the code might wrap. The split by newline would be just a bad idea. Instead you need to calculate the *scrollHeight* and line height and deduce from those values the number of lines
- if you want your line numbers to perfectly match position with the code editor lines, than obviously you cannot let that text be anything else but the exact same line height, size and font family as the hilite's contenteditable and PRE's CODE ones.
- you're not reusing well your JS code, the `updateLineNumbers()` should be a function that accepts an Element or multiple elements, the elHTML, elCSS, elJS). So use them as an optional Array argument
- When resizing the window you'll also have to recall that `updateLineNumbers` function
- Added a better Tab key handler function `tabToSpaces` to handle 4 spaces insertion instead of your `substring` solution

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77832699/383904

My suggestion (without offtopic HTML/CSS and commented out unused JS stuff):

```js
// Helper functions
const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelectorAll(sel);

// Code Highlighter App:
const elHTML = el(`[data-lang="html"]`);
const elCSS = el(`[data-lang="css"]`);
const elJS = el(`[data-lang="js"]`);
const elPreview = el("#preview");

const updateLineNumbers = (elLines, elTextarea) => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const scrollHeight = elTextarea.offsetHeight;
        const lineHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(elTextarea).lineHeight);
        const totLines = Math.round(scrollHeight / lineHeight);
        elLines.innerHTML = "<span></span>".repeat(totLines);
    });
};

const tabToSpaces = (evt) => {
    if (evt.key !== "Tab") return;
    const spaces = " ".repeat(4);
    evt.preventDefault();  // this will prevent us from tabbing out of the editor
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, spaces);
};

const updateTextareaHeight = (elTextarea) => {
    elTextarea.style.height = 0;
    elTextarea.style.height = elTextarea.scrollHeight + "px";
};

const hilite = (elCode, value) => {
    elCode.textContent = value;
    delete elCode.dataset.highlighted;
    hljs.highlightElement(elCode);
};

const preview = () => {
    // const encodedHTML = encodeURIComponent(elHTML.value);
    // const encodedCSS = encodeURIComponent(`<style>${elCSS.value}</style>`);
    // const encodedJS = encodeURIComponent(`<scr` + `ipt>${elJS.value}</scr` + `ipt>`);
    // const dataURL = `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,${encodedCSS + encodedHTML + encodedJS}`;
    // elPreview.src = dataURL;
};

const makeEditor = (elEditor) => {
    const elTextarea = el(".editor-textarea", elEditor);
    const elCode = el(".editor-highlight > code", elEditor);
    const elLines= el(".editor-lines", elEditor);

    elTextarea.addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
        tabToSpaces(evt);
    });

    elTextarea.addEventListener("input", () => {
        updateTextareaHeight(elTextarea);
        hilite(elCode, elTextarea.value);
        updateLineNumbers(elLines, elTextarea);
        preview();
    });

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        updateLineNumbers(elLines, elTextarea);
    }, true);

    updateTextareaHeight(elTextarea);
    hilite(elCode, elTextarea.value);
    updateLineNumbers(elLines, elTextarea);
};

// Initialize!

els(".editor").forEach(makeEditor);
preview();
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 1em/1.4 sans-serif;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.editor {
  --pad: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  /* DEMO ONLY */
  overflow: auto;
  background: #1e1e1e;
}

.editor-area {
  position: relative;
  padding: var(--pad);
  height: max-content;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.editor-highlight code,
.editor-textarea {
  padding: 0rem !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0;
}

.editor-highlight code,
.editor-textarea,
.editor-lines {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font: normal normal 14px/1.4 monospace;
}

.editor-textarea {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  color: transparent; /* Make text invisible */
  caret-color: hsl(50, 75%, 70%); /* But keep caret visible */
  border: 0;
  &:focus {
    outline: transparent;
  }
  &::selection {
    background: hsla(0, 100%, 75%, 0.2);
  }
}

.editor-highlight {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--pad);
  right: var(--pad);
  user-select: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.editor-lines {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: right;
  height: max-content;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: hsl(0 100% 100% / 0.6);
  padding: var(--pad); /* use the same padding as .hilite */
  overflow: visible !important;
  background: hsl(0 100% 100% / 0.05);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  & span {
    counter-increment: linenumber;
    &::before {
      content: counter(linenumber);
    }
  }
}


/* highlight.js customizations: */

.hljs {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/vs2015.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />


<h3>HTML</h3>

<div class="editor">
  <pre class="editor-lines"></pre>
  <div class="editor-area">
    <pre class="editor-highlight"><code class="language-html"></code></pre>
    <textarea class="editor-textarea" data-lang="html" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">&lt;h1 class="heading" title="test this" data-some='foo bar'>This is a Heading&lt;/h1>
&lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>CSS</h3>

<div class="editor">
  <pre class="editor-lines"></pre>
  <div class="editor-area">
    <pre class="editor-highlight"><code class="language-css"></code></pre>
    <textarea class="editor-textarea" data-lang="css" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">body {
  background: gold;    
}</textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

The above is not thoroughly tested. So make sure to do so.

---

One additional (but hard) improvement would be to make the *numbers* elements as tall as the parent, so even with a code of 30000 lines you would have as much as N SPANS to cover the parent height. On scroll you can move them in *"snap-reset"* and change the line values. I think this approach might be more performant to the browser than bloating the DOM with additional 30000 empty SPAN elements. Just as a food for thought.

Comment: Wow, a thousand thanks :) Thank you. I'll look at the code better tomorrow and I'll answer you, because it's late, i'm very tired, and now i'm going to sleep. In the meantime, i'll vote for your answer. Thank you. Until tomorrow! P.S: a little curiosity. In the Javascript, you added (even if empty) el.addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => { ?. I know that keydown is the event for a key press, so in my case what should it be for? Not Is the input event enough to show the output in the preview?

Comment: Inside the `"keydown"` there you should put the logic `if (event.key === "Tab") {` that inserts *N* spaces on TabKey press. Your code that was supposed to handle that was not working. Anyways edited and added that one too. In the future instead of `4` in `" ".repeat(4)` you can pass the configuration integer of the desired spaces to use like i.e: `" ".repeat(hiliteOptions.tabSpaces);`

Comment: I thank you :) You have been very kind. I appreciate. However, a simple little bizarre curiosity that creates problems for me: i tried to slightly increase the size of both the text and the numbers, but it breaks the alignment. For the text you have set font: 13px/1.4 monospace and for the numbers you have set font-size: 13px and line-height: 18.2px. I tried increasing text and numbers both to 14px (or even both to 15px), but the alignment breaks.I tried changing the line-height of the numbers, but it's still not aligned. How can I correctly use 14px for both numbers and text?

Comment: @Nodigap well spotted. Edited the CSS code with a rule for fonts that should be applied to all the three elements that need it.

Comment: There is something wrong. Using contenteditable="plaintext-only" is certainly better,but that doesn't answer what I asked in the comment above.You used 13px for both the size of the numbers and the size of the text.I would like to change it and use a slightly larger size: for example 14 or 15.If I set, for example, .hilite-numbers:{font-size 14px...} and then set .hilite-colors code, .hilite-editor {font: 13px/1.4 monospace...}, then the alignment of the lines with the numbers breaks. QUESTION: How can I correctly replace your 13px with 14px (or 15px) for both numbers and text?

Comment: @Nodigap nope. If you take a closer look at the edited code (CSS) you'll notice that everything related to the font is defined now in one single line. Change 14px to i.e: 16px and everything is larger and aligns perfectly. If you missed it... it's in this rule: `.hilite-colors code,
.hilite-editor,
.hilite-numbers {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font: normal normal 14px/1.4 monospace;
}`

Comment: Can we chat please? I would also like to ask you something about another question of mine that you answered, because I noticed some differences in the Javascript code itself. So let's clarify and I accept your well-deserved and kind answers :) How can we open a chat?

Comment: @Nodigap https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256609/code-editor-highlight